# Does Simplified Wrapper and Interface Generator generate Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, swig

I need to use swig to connect a C code with nodejs but after I run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install swig
```

and I use this command :

```
swig -javascript -node -c++ example.i
```

I got this error message:
swig erro:inrecognized javascript option.

Comment: I need some help plz

Answer (score 0):

You can find all supported languages of swig on http://www.swig.org/compat.html. As you can see Javascript was added in version 3.0.1. To install swig 3 use:

```
sudo apt-get install swig3
```

And to create a Javascript proxy use:

```
swig3 -javascript -node -c++ example.i
```